# Angular Share Component with Child Modules

Tags: angular

I have a parent.module that loads on its declarations the `SideboxComponent`.

The parent.component selector is `<app-parent>`, inside of it I can call `<app-sidebox>` selector because it's in the declarations.

The problem I am having is that I want to find a way of loading the same `<app-sidebox>` but from a child route, and without having to import SideboxComponent on every module of the child routes/modules, creating a shared module.

I just want to call the selector from any of the child but I am having hard time to find a way for it.

Let's say I want to load on the child /affiliates, how can I do it?

```
//parent.routing.ts
export const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '', 
        component: ParentComponent,
        children:[
            { path:'', redirectTo:'affiliates', pathMatch:'full' },
            { path: 'affiliates', loadChildren: './affiliates/affiliates.module#AffiliatesModule', data: { breadcrumb: 'Affiliates' } },
       ]
    }
];
```

EDIT:
This is the error I get:

```
[Error] ERROR – Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
'app-sidebox' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-sidebox' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-sidebox' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting? have you added `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in your parent component to load your child components?

Comment: @AmitChigadani I updated first post with error

Comment: The answer is in the question: the shared component must be declared and exported by a shared module, that must be imported by all modules that need to use it.

Comment: @JBNizet I read that as a possible solution of several other questions, however I believed that it would be possible to anyhow directly load the selector on children, that would avoid a ton of imports on several models... to load the component the model needs several other imports like Ng2CompleterModule, and few others ...

Comment: Then these modules should be imported and exported by the shared module too.